# Enable foreign users processes listing

Tags: nagios, process, top, ps

how can I enable under Debian 6 to list the processes of a foreign user? I have the user nagios but this user can only list his own processes.

Br

Answer (score 0):

[check_procs](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_procs) command accepts a "-u USER" argument to list the processes for the specified user.

You have to edit you command.cfg (the place where your nagios command are defined), and add something like this:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_user_procs
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w '$ARG1$' -c '$ARG2$' -u '$ARG3$'
    }
```

and create a service check for the user:

```
define service{
    use                             generic-service
    host_name                       YOUR-HOST-NAME   
    service_description             Total Processes
    check_command                   check_user_procs!250!400!USER_NAME_OR_ID
    }
```

you have to replace USER_NAME_OR_ID withe the user info you are checking for.

The first two number specify the limits for warning and critical events.

Comment: Thx for your answer. This is not working if I execute `check_procs` as user nagios. Because `ps aux` also lists only own processes. It must be a system wide setting on Debian not nagios.

Comment: This is just not true, actually... unless maybe you have selinux enabled, or something like that?

You can add "-vv" to check_procs to make it show you exactly what "ps" command it's using.

Comment: It works on my Debian Squeeze box, you should check for apparmor or selinux on your box as Keith suggested.